# Azure B2C page layouts missing translations in versions after 2.0.0

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How come Azure B2C Page Layouts are missing some translations versions *newer* from 2.0.0? Tested with languages such as Finnish, Estonian, Lithuanian, Polish, all have same issue. Tested with [latest templates](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/html-templates) as well, no difference.

E.g., 2.1.4 is missing translation as in the picture:

[image]

Also in pwd reset screen:

[image]

I can add manual translations to these, but according to documentation these languages should have full support and they did up until 2.0.0 Page Layout versions.

Answer (score 1):

In the doc you linked.

If you are using email verification via Display Control:
**Verification display control user interface elements**

- but_verify_code   `Verify code`
- success_send_code_msg `Verification code has been sent. Please copy it to the input box below.`

If you are using email verification with `verified.Email` claim:
**Sign-up and self-asserted pages user interface elements**

- ver_but_verify    `Verify code`
- ver_sent  `Verification code has been sent to:`

For individual claims like `signInName`, use the following syntax

````xml
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">Email Address</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="UserHelpText">Email address that can be used to contact you.</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="PatternHelpText">Please enter a valid email address.</LocalizedString>```
````

Comment: Sorry, this is not the question. Question is that although B2C documentation says it would contain all translations e.g., for Finnish, it does not anymore in 2.0.0+ versions and I need to manually add translations for pretty much all languages. Updated my question.